# Touchpad gets disabled after sometime after login

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I upgraded from Natty to Oneiric and use a external logitech mouse. When I login with both the touchpad and mouse enabled, the touchpad works fine. But if I continue using the mouse for sometime, and then try to use the touchpad it does not work. It is as if it is disabled for power saving.

I do not use any touchpad-indicator or tweak any settings. This did not happen when I was running natty.

How can I solve this? Do I submit a bug report?

Comment: I had similar problem with small different details. http://askubuntu.com/questions/70333/touchpad-freezing-after-upgerading-to-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting that disables the touchpad while you are using your keyboard that you can turn off.  I'm not sure whether that's likely to be related or not.  You can find that in the settings thing names Mouse and Trackpad.

I had similar issues initially with my computer until I rebooted a few times but now it seems to work okay.