# Touchpad Freezing on a Sony VAIO VPCF22S1E

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, touchpad, vaio

I have a Sony VAIO VPCF22S1E. I just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 . While upgrading (on downloading packages step) I lost my internet connection and 2-3 minutes later it resumed. I continued to download packages. And finally, upgrading is completed. Now I'm using 11.10 . But when I log in to Ubuntu after 2 minutes the touchpad will be unresponsive. I can't use it or the integrated buttons.

The **Disable touchpad while typing** option is turned off (suggested from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66081/touchpad-gets-disabled-after-sometime-after-login/66142#66142)) but it did not solve the problem.

How can I sure my packages downloaded and installed successfully? (As I said, I lost my connection while downloading packages)

*PS: I can use USB mouse.*

*PPS: I have tried `apt-get update` , `apt-get upgrade`*

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: @JorgeCastro which informations should i share about my touch pad ??

Comment: Run the commands listed in that question, and see if you see anything mentioning what kind of touchpad it is, then add that to your question, that will help us find out exactly what model it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix worked for first reboot but **now it's not working** :

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` to include `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”i8042.nopnp”`
2. Run: `sudo update-grub`
3. Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, When i face this, i open up terminal and logs myself out and then logs back in, this seems to be working for me, but this is not a solution but it seems to be working any way, The disabling the touch pad wont work as it happened again after doing so,

Answer (score -2):

Turn off disable touchpad while typing in mouse options and reboot.

Comment: He already tried that.